# SQL expecting 'with' command

Tags: mysql, sql

I started using MySQL recently and I am facing a problem. I created two tables using `create table` command and inserted value in the table. These two commands were executed successfully. Then I tried using `select` command. When I try to execute this command it shows

> "select" is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting: (, WITH

Here is my command:

```
 select 
 * 
 from Employee,
 where Gender="M" and NativePlace="Mumbai",
 order Hobby by desc;
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Should that comma after `"Mumbai" be there?

Comment: Likewise there shouldn't be a comma after `Employee`

Comment: And it should be `order by Hobby desc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of syntax errors in your query, try this:

```
select 
 * 
 from Employee
 where Gender='M' and NativePlace='Mumbai'
 order by Hobby desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the commas after `Employee` and `"Mumbai"` and you should be good.